# d3.js x is NaN?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When I use the `d3.js`, I get a problem.

The root in my js code is my JSON variable. I cannot find any `x` nor `y`, why? So, where is the problem? Forgive me for my poor English.

And my js code is:

```
var diameter = 960,
format = d3.format(",d");

var pack = d3.layout.pack()
    .size([diameter - 4, diameter - 4])
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var svg = d3.select("#mainBox1").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(2,2)");

var root = JSON.parse(jsonPath);
console.log(root);

{
    var node = svg.datum(root).selectAll(".node")
        .data(pack.nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "node" : "leaf node"; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

    node.append("title")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
    node.append("circle")enter code here
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; });
    node.filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }).append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".3em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
}
```

Comment: Without knowing both the data fed to this function and the location of error, this will not be possible to troubleshoot.

Comment: what is `jsonPath`? `JSON.parse` takes a JSON string, not a path.